# How to Use Delphi Translation Editor?

Tags: delphi, localization

I am using Delphi XE3's Translation Editor.

This is the screenshot:

[image]

The GUI is rather confusing as there are many columns I don't know their usages. What I can guess is the white cells are editable and I can input the translated contents, and set the status as "Translated".

I don't know what is the usage of "Previous 中文(简体, 中国)(original)" or "Previous (简体, 中国)(translated)".

The official document is at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Editing_Resource_Files_in_the_Translation_Manager. IT does not explain how to use the editor and what is the usage of the columns at all.

Comment: Asking for tutorials is off-topic for StackOverflow

Comment: Since you are using Delphi XE3 you should be looking at [Documentation for Delphi XE3(http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Editing_Resource_Files_in_the_Translation_Manager)] on this matter. There were many changes made to translation manager over the years.

Comment: Any way if I would have to guess I would say that Previous (original) and Previous (translated)  columns probably show the last saved translations in order to allow you to keep better track of translation changes.